# iBatus returns null when using #value# as a parameter

Tags: ibatis

I have a problem with select statement using iBatis, it returns null when I sumit the query as select soc from soc where soc.soc = #value#, but it returns correct result when I hard code the #value# as 'test'.

I have searched for solutions, and seems like the way that i am using is correct.
Is there anyone having a similar issue?

I am using iBatis 2.3 and oracle db.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are sending a null value in your class attribute (`value`). Debug the attribute value in your logs. You can debug by setting:

```
log4j.logger.com.ibatis=DEBUG
log4j.logger.java.sql.ResultSet=DEBUG
```

both of the above can be used to get the sql parameter value.